# How can I broadcast video live (preferably wirelessly)?

Tags: video, video-capture, live-video

#### Update

I've gotten plenty of feedback on the software solutions and the unanimous solution for having a handheld device to record video seems to be to use a mobile phone (I was hoping there'd be some webcam-like device with wifi support...)

**I'd appreciate more hardware suggestions now.** That is, what mobile phones have good video recording quality (and battery time)?

---

I'm looking for a solution to broadcast video live on the internet from a location (an apartment), with a device that can be carried around.

What options are there? I'm looking for complete solutions (i.e., what hardware to use, what software to use, how it should all be set up.)

Currently, I have my mobile phone (Nokia N95 8GB) with [Qik](http://www.qik.com/) installed connected to wifi, but unfortunately the videos get bad quality (especially since it's indoors with poor lighting) plus the battery gets used up quickly.

Comment: Do you mean on the internet or just on the local network of your apartment?

Comment: The video should be accessible on an internet address... But if I can just get it onto the local network there won't be any problem publishing it, so any way works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. http://flixwagon.com/  Live video
   streaming from your cell phone
2. http://www.ustream.tv/mobile  Live
   video streaming from your phone
3. http://qik.com/info/product_highlight
   Live video streaming from your phone
   Robert Scoble loves Qik
4. http://www.kyte.com/solutions/pg/tv_film
   Live video streaming (I find the site quite confusing)

Best wishes!  It can be done!!

Answer (score 1):

[Bambuser](http://bambuser.com/) can probably do what you're looking for, if you want to use a mobile ([yours](http://m.bambuser.com/select_model.php?b=Nokia), or any other which is listed in this [page](http://m.bambuser.com/broadcast.php)) for directly streaming to the internet.

More information [here](http://bambuser.com/help):

> **How much does this cost?**
>
> Our base service is free to consumers and non profit organisations.
>
> When broadcasting over the GSM network, your operator might charge you for costs associated with data transfer. We recommend you to get a flat rate contract with your operator. Our broadcasting application also support Wi-Fi based access, which might be a great alternative to the GSM network in some cases, if your phone has Wi-Fi support.
>
> **Can I do Private broadcasts?**
>
> Oh yes you can.

Comment: Nice, I'll bookmark that one! But I'm also looking for an update in hardware... either a new mobile phone with better camera than N95, or some other kind of device. Suggestions?